# Update the interface in the secondary process

Tags: c#, multithreading, selenium

I'm using selenium to perform the automation of a web task and I'm generating a simple log ... However, I would like to "unlock" the interface for the log to be inserted in real time and not at the end of the whole process.

Simple log:

```
void log(string texto)
{
     listBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
     {
         listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), texto));
     });

}
```

How im using:

```
//Selenium Code Here (eg.: driver = new ChromeDriver();)
log("ChromeDriver Started!");
```

But nothing happens, the interface keeps being updated at the end of every process.